# FlatList scrollToOffset triggering multiple scroll events

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview, flatlist

I have a FlatList with items that can be selected via the arrow keys, and I'm scrolling to keep the selected item in the FlatList window.

I'm calculating the scroll offset of the currently selected item and calling `scrollToOffset`. I'm using this method since my items don't have a strict, list-like layout, so I can't use `scrollToIndex`.

On one of the calls to `scrollToOffset`, the `onScroll` handler gets fired multiples (when it should only be fired once); it gets called the first time with the correct scroll offset that I'm passing to `scrollToOffset`, but then it gets called another 2-3 times with the incorrect scroll offset.

Any clues as to what's happening? I can guarantee that I'm only calling `scrollToOffset` once per arrow key press. It's a bit too difficult to create a playground for this considering how many moving pieces there are.